# Existence of super Wilson numbers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, factorial

One could define super Wilson primes as primes $p$ for which there exists a natural number $k$ such that $(p-1)!+1=p^k$. One easily checks that 2, 3, and 5 are such super Wilson primes, where only 5 actually is a Wilson prime. The only other known Wilson primes are 13 and 563, but which are not "super". One easily checks that if $p\ge 5$ is a super Wilson prime, then $k$ must be even.

Question: Are there more such super Wilson primes? Or not?

Comment: I believe that is highly unlikely, as $(p-1)!$ and $p^k$ are such special, rare numbers. (although I still don't have a proof)

Comment: How can we see that $k$ must be even for $n\ge 5$ ? If Brocard's problem has no solution $p\ge 7$, this would imply that $k$ cannot be even. But this is yet open. It has however been checked upto a very high limit. And I think, the Wilson primes have been checked upto a quite high limit as well.

Comment: $(p-1)!+1=p^k$ is equivalent to $(p-1)!=p^k-1$ is equivalent to $(p-1)!=(p-1)(1+p+p^2 +\dots +p^{k-1})$ is equivalent to $(p-2)!=1+p+p^2 +\dots +p^{k-1}$. If $p\ge 5$, then the left-hand side is even. Hence, $k-1$ must be odd. So, $k$ must be even.